# org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException:Unable to access a link through eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium, firefox

I am trying to access a link through eclipse.Link for same is :
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/first-test-case/

Below is the command for same:

```
                WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
```

I am using selenium 2.4 , firefox 53, geckodriver-v0.9.0-win64.
It opens an empty window for me and not able to access facebook.

I have also tried

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\ToolsQA\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
```

It also couldn't help.
I am getting following exception:
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
What else can I do?

Comment: Can you bump up your Selenium version to 3.4.0, geckodriver to 0.16.1 & Mozilla Firefox to 53.x ? Put your exact code in the Question area along with the error stack trace?

Comment: remove " DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);"

Answer (score 0):

It appears Selenium and Firefox have difficulty talking to each other - I suspect Firefox 'evolve' changes over a number of releases, so backward and forward compatibility are not always guaranteed, and incompatibility always seems to generate the same error.

The reason for the **Unable to connect error** is that the version of Selenium Server does not know how to work with the newer version of Firefox. You need to download a newer version of the Selenium Server that supports the newer version of Firefox.

You can download latest version of selenium from here : http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Hope it will help you :)